# With Flutter, how can I display Firebase Auth error messages caught within an AuthService class within a separate log in page widget?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a Registration Page with my sign up form and then an AuthService class I call to sign up the user, returning a mapped custom User class. I can check if the result of the function call is not null and therefore navigate my user to the home page, but I can't work out how to setState or similar to actually show the user the Firebase Auth messages in my Registration page, as the try/catch block is within my auth service class.

This is my abbreviated Registration screen widget:

```
class RegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegistrationScreenState createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //abbreviated...
                RoundedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, displayName);
                     if (result != null) {
                       Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, Home.id, (_) => false);
                      } 
                     }
                  }
                }
  }
```

The registerWithEmailAndPassword is within an imported AuthService class auth.dart:

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  //create User object
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid, displayName: user.displayName) : null;
  }

  //auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
    .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  // register
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password, String displayName) async {
                      try { 
                      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
                      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

                      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
                    } catch(e) {
                      print(e);
                    } 
                      } 
  }
```

If I then test this with a badly formatted email, I correctly print to the console:

```
flutter: PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL, The email address is badly formatted., null)
```

However how can I use that PlatformException to setState or similar within my registration screen to show the e.message to the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class like this;

```
class Errors {
   static String show(String errorCode) {
     switch (errorCode) {
       case 'ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE':
         return "This e-mail address is already in use, please use a different e-mail address.";

       case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
         return "The email address is badly formatted.";

       case 'ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL':
         return "The e-mail address in your Facebook account has been registered in the system before. Please login by trying other methods with this e-mail address.";

       case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
         return "E-mail address or password is incorrect.";

       default:
         return "An error has occurred";
     }
   }
}
```

And then, when you get PlatformException error, you can show an alert dialog to user like this;

```
try { 
   AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
   FirebaseUser user = result.user;

   return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
} catch(e) {
   print(Errors.show(e.code));   // On this line, call your class and show the error message.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify the line where I should call that class please? I’m not sure how I can show the message to the user - I call my registerWithEmailAndPassword from within my Registration screen and if it’s successful, I want to trigger my Navigator, if not, setState or similar to show the error. I don’t see how I use my Result to distinguish between a successful User being returned or an error being returned, as the error is being printed within my separate AuthService class in a separate file. 
If I try if (result ==error) it’s not defined and I still need to catch successful login.

Comment: Okay, create an errors.dart file and paste theese codes. Also remove the try-catch on your AuthService, and check try catch on your build, on result. It'll work. Use just once on your build. If something wrong, do it your catch with an AlertDialog.

Comment: I've removed the try/catch from my auth.dart file and moved it to the registration_page.dart file, but the PlatformException still gets thrown within my auth.dart services file, rather than my registration_page.dart sign up file, so it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It should work. Did you do like "_auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, displayName).catchError(onError){
    ...
  }"

Comment: Slow reply sorry - yes thank you, got it working with this in the end! Thanks for the advice.